# Rspec test double not behaving as I would expect inside rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Controller action:

```
class GoogleOauth2sController < ApplicationController
  def new
    google_drive_oauth2 = GoogleDriveOauth2.new
    redirect_to google_drive_oauth2.authorization_uri
  end
end
```

test:

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'

describe GoogleOauth2sController do
  let(:google_drive_oauth2) { double("GoogleDriveOauth2", :authorization_uri => "www.reddit.com") }

  describe "GET #new" do
    it "should redirect user to google oauth2 authorization page" do
      get :new
      expect(response.redirect_url).to include("accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth")
    end
  end
end
```

I would expect this test to FAIL, because i created a test double of the "GoogleDriveOauth" class and stubbed out its method to return "www.reddit.com". Yet the test passe, and calls out to the google oauth2 auth page.

My goal is to avoid making the api calls to Google in order to form the URI in the first place (the responsibility of the GoogleDriveOauth2 class). As far as i can tell from the documentation this should stub out the method, what i'm i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject the double into your test. RSpec doesn't know when/where the double should be used. Try this:

```
describe GoogleOauth2sController do
  let(:google_drive_oauth2) { double("GoogleDriveOauth2", :authorization_uri => "www.reddit.com") }

  describe "GET #new" do
    it "should redirect user to google oauth2 authorization page" do
      expect(GoogleDriveOauth2).to receive(:new).and_return(google_drive_oauth2)
      get :new
      expect(response.redirect_url).to include("accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth")
    end
  end
end
```

I would expect this test to fail now.